# require.js i18n module - how to load a language from server?

Tags: backbone.js, internationalization, requirejs

My app setup is require js with backbone js.

I've got a situation where I'd like to be able to get the appropriate language for an unknown user from browser navigator object, but where i could also load the preferred language for a known user from the server if this information exists.

is there a way to accomplish this? the only access point i could find is in require.config, but normally this is being loaded before any data arrives from the server. 
thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you been able to achieve this ? I have the same problem

Comment: Following link might help you http://pedromadias.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/backbone-js-and-i18n/
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640630/javascript-i18n-internationalization-frameworks-libraries-for-client-side-use

https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js

Answer (score 0):

Is there any default language you have set to a user?
First on log-in bring user information from server

you may use this kind of code

```
setLanguage: function(languageCode){
enter code here
        this.set("languageCode",languageCode);
        if(this.isAvailable(i18n)){`enter code here`
            i18n.userSelected(languageCode);
        }else{`enter code here`
            this.showErrorMsg(window.i18n.msgStore['default_language_is_set_to'] + " " + constants.language[languageCode]);
        }
    },

set:function(key, value){
         localStorage.setItem(key, value);`enter code here`
    },
```

Here the language is also set into the local storage so that later on you can access it